# C++ Very Sleepy strange results

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm currently programming an SDL Network Game, everything is perfect ... But my game only runs at 30fps, so I ran a Very Sleepy analysis.
First strange effect, very sleepy increase the perfs of my Game to 60Fps ... ( Why ? ) 
And secondly, there is a lot of SDL_LogCritical calls ( you can get the report here : http://puu.sh/gauEi/9a852462e6.png ). And nothing is shown in the console.
( I also use SDLNet, with TCP protocol, there is no packet loose ).

Moreover, I overwritten the output for SDL Logs :

```
void log(void* userdata, int category, SDL_LogPriority priority, const char* message) { 
    std::cout << "Log : " << message << std::endl;
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDLNet_Init();
    SDL_LogSetOutputFunction(log, NULL);
    SDL_LogCritical(1, "TEST LOG");

}
```

And I can see the "TEST LOG" in the console. So the SDL_LogCritical which consumme 30% doesn't output everything .

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've run into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong, but frequent calls to a logging function indicate that something is wrong and SDL tries to tell you about it. However, the lack of output might be caused by you explicitely or implicitely disable logging to the console. Your use of Network might indicate your not looking at the right console to see these warnings. It's all a bit hard to diagnose with the lack of information given.

Performance increase due to debugging is strange, but can often be explained by the fact that the debugger doesn't use exactly the same environment as you do when running normally.

OK, so you're not seeing output when something else calls SDL's log functionality. This points to the messages being logged somehow being below necessary priority. Compare [SDL's source code](http://fossies.org/dox/SDL2-2.0.3/SDL__log_8c_source.html#l00269) to find out how that could be happening. Maybe you should, at this point, use a debugger to set breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you ! 
I forgot to precise that I overwritten the output for SDL's logs :


void log(void* userdata, int category, SDL_LogPriority priority, const char* message) { 
 std::cout << "Log : " << message << std::endl;
}  
SDL_LogSetOutputFunction(log, NULL);

And I works when I manually launch a SDL_LogCritical ...

Yes, I don't understand why it increase my perfs but the result is the same when the project is in debug or release mode ...

Comment: Well, @Mushroom15, then quickly add that info to your original question, before it gets downvoted to hell.